# Mocking the Stripe Customer service with attached Cards

Tags: php, stripe-payments, mockery

I'm writing unit and integration tests for a payment platform I'm building with Stripe and need to mock the customer object using Mockery, unfortunately I've hit a bit of a wall when trying to create a Stripe customer with an attached Card object.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Please show something that you tried, and what the result was.

Comment: I have answered my own question, the answer was simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I posted this question, I realised that I have already created a service to abstract Stripe functionality, and as such, I can simply extend that functionality to include `createCard` `updateCard` `retrieveCard` and `deleteCard` methods:

```
class StripeService implements StripeServiceContract
{
    public function createCard(Stripe\Customer $customer, $source, $default = true)
    {
        $source = $customer->sources->create(compact('source'));
        if ($default) {
            $customer->default_source = $source->id;
            $customer->save();
        }
        return $source;
    }

    public function retrieveDefaultCard(Stripe\Customer $customer)
    {
        return $customer->sources->retrieve($customer->default_source);
    }
}
```

Then I can mock this using mockery:

```
Mockery::mock(StripeServiceContract::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('createCard')->andReturnUsing(function ($customer, $id, $default) {
        return new Stripe\Card($id);
    });
    $mock->shouldReceive('retrieveCard')->andReturnUsing(function ($id) {
        return new Stripe\Card($id);
    });
});
```